# Map<UUID, String> map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Why does this works in Groovy:

```
Map<String, String> map = ["k1"  : "p1",  "k2"  : "p2"]
```

but this does not ?

```
Map<UUID, String> map = [UUID.randomUUID() : "p1", UUID.randomUUID() : "p2"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the keys in `()`:

```
Map<UUID, String> map = [(UUID.randomUUID()): "p1", (UUID.randomUUID()): "p2"]
```

Groovy assumes, that the tokens before the `:` are just string keys (e.g. your first example could also be written as: `[k1: "p1", ...]` and would work the same.  But since your method calls there are no valid strings (and you don't even want them to be interpreted as strings) it fails compiling.

See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_maps

> When you need to pass variable values as keys in your map definitions, you must surround the variable or expression with parentheses